# using ng-if to display html content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I want a way to display if something is not present then display something else.

so far I have this:

```
<span ng-if="likes.length = 0"> No hacks to display </span>
```

so if the length is zero then display this.

this code filters to order if present:

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line hacks-hack"
    ng-repeat="hack in hacksCtrl.hacks | orderBy: likes.length : reverse | filter:searchText | filter:hacksCtrl.filterStatus"
    ng-click=hacksCtrl.goToHack(hack.id)>
```

not sure what i am missing, thanks

Answer (score 2):

`=` operator assign a value to the variable on the left side of the expression.

Use `===` or `==` for comparison.

```
<span ng-if="likes.length === 0"> No hacks to display </span>
```

`===` operator won't do the type conversion before the comparison while `==` does the type conversion before the comparison.

`===` (Identity operator) is the correct way to compare if both the operands are of same type.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/rebara/edit?html,css,js,console,output) is minimal a working sample

Comment: ok that makes sense, but still wont render it even if the list of hacks disappear

Comment: @TheHurricane you might have another script error. See my updated answer which has a minimal working sample which solves your original question.

Comment: yours is displaying alongside though, i want it to appear when the list is blank

Comment: It is displaying that span when the `likes` is empty.

Comment: ok got ya. mine displays for about a second, then all the hacks appear, then i will search for one that is not there and then the message does not re appear. so how do you get it to display everytime rather than a one off which is what mine is doing for some reason

Comment: You might have some code which is updating it. Can you put the minimal code needed to reproduce your issue inside a jsbin and share ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ng-show instead of ng-if? ng-if only renders on the page if that statement is true. And where you're using a filter, I would suggest trying ng-show where it is simple text and wouldn't really effect rendering time.

Comment: it appears initially, then the array gets populated, then i will search for something not in the array but the message does not pop back up

Comment: It appears, after looking at your example again, you're checking likes === 0 and should possibly be checking hacksCtrl.hacks. Or am I misunderstanding your code? Could you create a simple plunkr or something to give me a sample to go off of?

Comment: i am now doing this `<div ng-show="hacksCtrl.hacks.length == 0"> No hacks to display </div>`